# Errors ONLY while doing Product --> Archive with semantic issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4, archiving

If I compile it to device or simulator, it works well. But when I do Product --> Archive, it  errors:

```
Login.m
! Semantic Issue
  Use of undeclared identifier 'kLogin_URL'
```

But this works on simulator and device

I am using Xcode version Version 4.6 (4H127). Here is the constant file.

```
#ifndef MyMobileApp_AllUrls_h
    #define MyMobileApp_AllUrls_h

    #ifdef QA
        #define kLogin_URL              @"https://b2bgateway.qa.mycompany.com/authenticate"
        #define ktran_URL               @"https://b2bgateway.qa.mycompany.com/.../lookup"

        #define LOGIN_REQUEST_TIMEOUT   15.0f
        #define TRAN_REQ_TIMEOUT        60.0f
    #endif

    #ifdef PROD
        #define kLogin_URL              @"https://b2bgateway.mycompany.com/authenticate"
        #define ktran_URL               @"https://b2bgateway.mycompany.com/.../lookup"

        #define LOGIN_REQUEST_TIMEOUT   15.0f
        #define TRAN_REQ_TIMEOUT        30.0f
    #endif
#endif
```

The contents of -prefix.pch is

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "AllUrls.h"
#endif
```

Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you've double checked your build configuration to make sure PROD is properly defined?

Comment: My build settings preprocessor macros is currently set as QA=1 DEBUG=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your build settings preprocessor macros include `PROD` under your release configuration.

Per your comment, Just wanted to make sure this is what you did.

```
#ifdef QA
    #define kLogin_URL              @"https://b2bgateway.qa.mycompany.com/authenticate"
    #define ktran_URL               @"https://b2bgateway.qa.mycompany.com/.../lookup"

    #define LOGIN_REQUEST_TIMEOUT   15.0f
    #define TRAN_REQ_TIMEOUT        60.0f
#else
    #define kLogin_URL              @"https://b2bgateway.mycompany.com/authenticate"
    #define ktran_URL               @"https://b2bgateway.mycompany.com/.../lookup"

    #define LOGIN_REQUEST_TIMEOUT   15.0f
    #define TRAN_REQ_TIMEOUT        30.0f
#endif
```

Comment: Ok, should I have both QA as well as prod

Comment: Yep, `QA` in the same place as `DEBUG` and `PROD` in the release section.

Comment: Or you can do away with `PROD` and change your `#ifdef` to `#else`

Comment: You are right. I made it to #else and error disappeared. One more question before I accept the answer. If I keep it the way it is, where is the release section

Comment: Awesome. I added a bit of code to my answer just to make sure we're on the same page.